# Compare image from file and image created from canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, jasmine, protractor

(I'm testing with Protractor and Jasmine, and I've also included [image-diff](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/js-imagediff) and node-canvas in my project.)

I need to compare two images and make sure they are the same. One is saved in my file structure and the other is created from canvas. I am able to convert the canvas to image and also load the image from the file. Here's what I have:

```
var imagediff = require('../node_modules/js-imagediff/js/imagediff.js');
var Canvas = require('canvas');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
beforeEach(function () {
  jasmine.addMatchers(imagediff.jasmine);
});
function loadImage (url, callback) {
  var image;
  fs.readFile(url, function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    image = new Canvas.Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      callback(image);
    };
    image.src = data;
  });
  return image;
}
it('should work', function () { 
 //executeScript is needed to get the canvas element and convert it
 browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
    var can = document.querySelector('#workspace-canvas'); 
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var data = can.toDataURL("image/png");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = data;
    //this code below shows that the image was converted properly
    // var link = document.createElement('a');
    // link.href = img.src;
    // link.download = 'image1.png';
    // link.click();
    return data;
  }).then(function(result) {
    newData = result;
    var imgPath = path.join(__dirname, './images/image1.png');
    loadImage(imgPath, function(image) {
      console.log('loadImage');
      var canvas = new Canvas();
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      oldData = data;
      //TODO: do a comparison here! 
      done();
    });
  });
```

My question is how do I compare the two images and make sure they are the same? I thought comparing the data URI would work but it doesn't. I'd really like to use image-diff but I'm not sure how to do that. Please help me!

Comment: Take a look at [`browser.executeScript`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript), which allows to inject and execute custom code on a page under test and return values from there back to a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it. I used `fs.writeFile` to save the new image to my project and then load that image and compare both images with image-diff.

```
var imagediff = require('../node_modules/js-imagediff/js/imagediff.js');
var Canvas = require('canvas');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
beforeEach(function () {
  jasmine.addMatchers(imagediff.jasmine);
});
function loadImage (url, callback) {
  var image;
  fs.readFile(url, function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    image = new Canvas.Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      callback(image);
    };
    image.src = data;
  });
  return image;
}
function writeFile (buffer, fileName) {
  fs.writeFile(fileName, buffer, function (err) {
    if(err) { console.log('ERROR', err); }
  });
}
function dataURItoBuffer (dataURI, fileName) {
  var byteString = dataURI.split(',')[1];
  var buffer = new Buffer(byteString, 'base64');
  writeFile(buffer, fileName);
}
it('should work', function () { 
  //fileName is defined somewhere else
  var filePath = './images' + fileName + '.png';
  //executeScript is needed to get the canvas element and convert it
  browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
    var can = document.querySelector('#workspace-canvas'); 
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var data = can.toDataURL("image/png");
    return data;
  }).then(function(result) {
    dataURItoBuffer(result, fileName);
    var oldImagePath = path.join(__dirname, './images/' + fileName + '.png');
    var newImagePath = path.join(__dirname, filePath);
    loadImage(oldImagePath, function(image) {
      image1 = image;
      loadImage(newImagePath, function(image){
        image2 = image;
        expect(imagediff.equal(image1, image2, 50)).toBeTruthy(); // 50 pixel tolerance
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The API of [imagediff](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/js-imagediff), has the `imagediff.equal(a,b)` function, that gets 2 `Image` objects, which should help you in this case.

If this won't help you, you could always md5 hash both of them and make sure the checksums are equal, more info on this [md5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum), [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).

Comment: I guess I'll give you the bounty since you are the only one who wrote an answer